# Is it possible to use R's zeallot library with the future library?

Tags: r, r-future, zeallot

This works fine:

```
library(zeallot)
c(v1, v2, v3) %<-% list(10, 20, 30)
```

This does not:

```
library(zeallot)
library(future)
c(v1, v2, v3) %<-% list(10, 20, 30)
```

because `future` overrides `zeallot's` *parallel assignment* operator.

```
The following objects are masked from ‘package:zeallot’:

    %->%, %<-%
```

Does this mean it is not possible to use `zeallot` with `future`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see two options.

1. Ensure that `zealot`'s `%<-%` takes precedence by loading `zealot` last.

   ```r
   library(future)
   library(zeallot)
   c(v1, v2, v3) %<-% list(10, 20, 30)
   ```
2. Use explicit namespace calling when using `%<-%` in functional (not infix) form.

   ```r
   library(zeallot)
   library(future)
   zeallot::`%<-%`(c(v1, v2, v3), list(10, 20, 30))
   ```

Comment: You can use the `exclude` option in `library` as well `library(future, exclude = c("%->%", "%<-%"));
 c(v1, v2, v3) %<-% list(10, 20, 30)`

Answer (score 1):

I like this question. :)

You can exclude some of the function from one of these lib white you import them, such as:

```r
library (zeallot, exclude = c("%->%", "%<-%"));
```

or:

```r
library (future, exclude = c("%->%", "%<-%"));
```

Then give them new names, such as:

```r
`%<=%` = zeallot::`%<-%` ;
`%=>%` = zeallot::`%->%` ;
```

or:

```r
`%<--%` = future::`%<-%` ;
`%-->%` = future::`%->%` ;
```

Now, you can just use the new names.

You can do that things for just one library or both as your wish. :)